# Check mark Animation after a successfull login

Tags: android

I am creating a login in android studio and after a user logs in, I have set up a text view that say welcome + email you logged in with. I would also like to have an animated tick icon to show a form of a success [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqHBa.png) below the text view that shows the welcome statement.
could anyone help? Something close that picture

Comment: Please, show your code. We cannot help to you then we don't see how you implement you business logic.

Comment: Please don't expect us to write a code for you.. at least show something what you have tried and where you are stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a custom `AlertDialog` with the messages you want to display using a `TextView` and an `ImageView` that got an animated check gif or a `VideoView` that plays a check mark video. Animating something like that is simple, if you know how to create one though. You can declare the `AlertDialog`'s variable globally that you will `show` when the login is successful then simultaneously start something like a `Handler` that acts as a timer for when you want to `dismiss` the `AlertDialog`.

For the resources you'll need, it's up to you here or how you'll get/create one. Hope this helps you somehow.